# How to insert Polyhedralsurface into POSTGIS?

Tags: postgis, 3d

I am unable to store a polyhedralsurface object in my POSTGIS database.

My table has two columns:

```
name character varying,
geom geometry(POLYHEDRALSURFACE)
```

I am trying to insert the following geometry:

```
INSERT INTO public.geometries(
        name, geom)
VALUES ('Cube', ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYHEDRALSURFACE( 
((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)),  
((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)), 
((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)), 
((1 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0)),  
((0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)),  
((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1)) 
)'));
```

but POSTGIS throws an error:

```
Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution :D

You can either set your geometry as GeometryZ at time of creation like this

```
geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326)
```

Or use AddGeometryColumn function

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'geometries', 'geom', 4326, 'GEOMETRY', 3 );
```

If anyone has a better solution, please comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change your geometrytype to POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ, that should do the trick. This is not well documented in the postgis documentation I think.